# Is it possible to add an array into another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I need to add ann array to an existing array.

If i have an array

```
var array = ["foo", "baah"];
```

then, what i need to do is to add an array into the existing one. So it ends up looking like

```
var array = ["foo", "baah", ["newfoo", "newbaah"]];
```

i need to do it client site, so using javascript or JQuery. Anyone who can help me? If i can't add a array to a array, is i then possible to add an object

Something like

```
var array = ["foo", "baah", /*myObject containing 2 item*/];
```

just ask for more info if needed.

Comment: Everything is possible. Just tell us what you have tried so far, so that we can guide you in that direction.

Comment: Did you try pushing the second array in the first one? Take a look at [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: .push is what we usually  use for this

Comment: "Almost Everything is possible"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arrOne = [1,2,3];
const arrTwo = [4,5];
arrOne[arrOne.length] = arrTwo;
console.log(arrOne);
```

You don't need to use `.push()`, you can use index notation.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But i found that my problem is happening before i try to add 1 array into another. Ty for your comment

Answer (score 2):

Just `.push` will do it

```js
var array1 = ["foo", "baah"];
var array2 = ["newfoo", "newbaah"];

array1.push(array2)

console.log(array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `push`:

```js
var array1 = ["foo", "baah"];
var array2 = ["newfoo", "newbaah"];
array1.push(array2);
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via `...` spread operator.

```js
var array1 = ["foo", "baah"];
var array2 = ["newfoo", "newbaah"];

var array3 = [...array1, array2];

console.log(array3);
```

`.push` will mutate your first array but this one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

**Push**

You can use push to add one array to another

```
var a = [1,2]
var b =[3,4]

a.push(b) //[1,2,[3,4]]
```

**unshift**

This is similar to push but adds the array to the first

```
a.push(b) //[[3,4],1,2]
```

**concat**

```
a.concat(b)//[1,2,3,4]
```

`concat` returns a new array rather than `push` and `unshift` which adds in the existing array